# Fatal exception error in Android

Tags: android, fatal-error

Can any one tell me what this logcat is demanding for?

Suggestions please.

Thanks for your precious time!..

**Adapter_available.java**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) 
    {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_available_layout, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt_plname    = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_planname);
        holder.txt_price     = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_price);
        holder.txt_size      = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_size);
        holder.btn_buy_ = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_buy);

//          convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


    Available_contents contents =  originalist.get(position);

    holder.txt_price.setText("K "+contents.price);
    holder.txt_size.setText(contents.size);
    holder.txt_plname.setText(contents.planname);

    }
return convertView;
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at org.twinkle.bemobile.Adapter_available.getView(Adapter_available.java:57)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2472)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15524)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5109)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15524)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5109)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15524)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5109)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15524)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5109)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2397)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15524)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5109)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15524)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5109)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15524)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5109)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15524)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5109)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15524)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5109)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15524)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5109)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15524)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5109)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2397)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15524)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1986)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1227)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1400)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1120)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4604)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at android.os.Handler.dispatch
```

Comment: Post `getView` of adapter

Comment: check for return **null** in `getView()` function in your adapter.

Comment: Yes. Prolem is in 'org.twinkle.bemobile.Adapter_available.getView(...);'

Comment: @Raghunandan please visit my question again ive posted getview of adaper

Comment: deathember and Vladimir are true. There is a Null value at line#57 in Adapter_available.getView(). Put a break point you start application in debugging mode to know which variable is null.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 18:29:04.705: E/AndroidRuntime(12701):    at org.twinkle.bemobile.Adapter_available.getView(Adapter_available.java:57)` - line 57 of getView is the exact location of the problem.  My guess is this line, since you do not set the tag anywhere.  `holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();`. Please read your tutorial again.

Comment: @Prabu the code will not help as its not clear what is at line#57. Please debug to know which variable is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `getView`

You use a `ViewHolder` pattern. You initialize views when `convertView` is null. You set the tag to `convertView`.

```
convertView.setTag(holder);
```

If `convertView` is not null

```
holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
```

As Simon suggested in his commented

```
//  convertView.setTag(holder); // commented
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); // using get tag
    // this line probably gives you NPE
```

[How ListView's recycling mechanism works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

Probably the above link has a better explanation how list recycling works

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Using `ViewHolder` Pattern helps in smooth scrolling and performance.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) 
    {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_available_layout, parent,false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt_plname    = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_planname);
        holder.txt_price     = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_price);
        holder.txt_size      = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_size);
        holder.btn_buy_ = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_buy);

        convertView.setTag(holder); 
        // this was commented. no need to do that
       } 
       else
       { 
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
        // if convertVIew is not null initialize the holder using convertView.getTag

       }  


    Available_contents contents =  originalist.get(position);

    holder.txt_price.setText("K "+contents.price);
    // set text to text view and update it here 
    holder.txt_size.setText(contents.size);
    holder.txt_plname.setText(contents.planname);

    }
return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Please help to OP, and others.  What did you change and why?

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks for your concern.it made me clear..Thank you once  again :)

Answer (score 1):

you don't use SetTag() in your code but you want use following code:

```
holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
```

you must first setTag() then get that and you need else statement for checking getting Tag.

```
if (convertView == null) 
    {

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        // define parameter
        convertView.setTag(holder); 

       } 
       else
       { 
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }  
       // setText and other thing
  return convertView;
```